# Chrome Safari get .offset() of hidden elements but Firefox doesn't

Tags: jquery, firefox, offset

I am having a difficulty calculating the offset using jQuery offset(), in Safari and Chrome it works fine, but Firefox seems to not account of the hidden elements which I have on the . Is there a more consistent way of getting the offset, perhaps without jQuery, as long as it works on all browsers the same way? Otherwise I am considering to detect the browser and  apply a workaround.

Comment: firefox should do that, can you post some code, maybe it is something else that causes it to fail?

Comment: Firefox gets the offset short by 57px, I checked everywhere and I didn't find any overflow in the first place. I'll try to post a code.